# add one category 'id' coloumn to identify records in all tables in one db

Tags: database, database-design

This question is just to clear one scenario and ask for suggestion regarding a db design.

I have four tables:

1. Category
2. Users
3. Reports
4. Schedules

All the records in users,reports, and schedules need to be identified on the basis off category.

So my question is according to above scenario is it good approach to add category id in all tables? or is there any other approach i can adopt to achieve this?

Comment: Is there any relationship between other tables like Reports and Schedules ? If so then just add Category column in Reports table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to choosing when to normalized and denormalized tables.

Normalization is organization of columns and tables to remove data redundancy while denormalization is the process of attempting to optimize the read performance of a database by adding redundant data or by grouping data.

**Advantage of Normalization:**

1. Avoid redundant data reducing the size of the DB.
2. Better structure and design of your database

**Disadvantage of Normalization:**

1. You will joining many tables

**Advantage of Denormalization:**

1. Better performance of queries
2. Reduce the number of tables

**Disadvantage of Denormalization:**

1. Duplicate data
2. Misleading sometimes

> normalize until it hurts, denormalize until it work

This article is a good read. 
[Maybe Normalizing Isn't Normal](https://blog.codinghorror.com/maybe-normalizing-isnt-normal/)

Comment: so according to this i prefer you are suggesting not to normalize and put the id in all tables to avoid joins and achieve performance?

Comment: @WasifTanveer if your data is not quiet large, normalize your tables and if your dealing with very large volume of data denormalized your tables to improve performance. For now, your the one who can determine on what to follow :)

Comment: data is large, and i would like the queries to be fast also . so De-normalize is the way to go

Comment: @WasifTanveer yah nice catch

Comment: @WasifTanveer np! :)

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your application logic.

> All the records in users,reports, and schedules need to be identified
>   on the basis off category

Scenario No 1:
*First a category is defined then a user is defined under the category. The user may have reports, schedules and ...* 
It shows that `User` table has a mandatory foreign key from `Category` and other tables will have a mandatory foreign key from user.
 No need to add category FK to other tables.
Scenario No 2:
 A user is defined, A category is defined, a user can be assigned to a category(s) (we will have `user-category` table)
A category may have reports.
A user in a category can run a report under registered category.... 
Categories FK is needed in other tables.

So you have mentioned **Names**(user, category, report ... ) in you question.
 You didn't mentioned **Verbs** that shows functions of you application.
Application logic containing names and verbs makes data-modeling.

Comment: categories can be considered as fields/domains, and users and schedules and reports have separate links with categories they may or may not be assigned to users, like one schedule is create for one category but it is not assigned to any user. and same like one report is generated for one category but no user.